# Create an array minimizing sum of square deviations to another array

Tags: optimization, arrays

**Problem**

Let `y` be an array of float numbers (of length $n$) bounded in the range [0,1]. I am trying to compute the array `x` that respects the following criteria:

- `x` must be of length $n$ too
- `x` must also be bounded in the range [0,1]
- No two values of `x` must be closer to each other than $\epsilon$. That is $ \epsilon \le x_i - x_j  \space \forall i \neq j$

So far, there are an infinite number of possible solutions. There is therefore a statistic to optimize though.

- The sum of square differences between `x` and `y` must be minimized. That is $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2$ must be minimized.

**In short**

I want to find `x` given `y` such as

$$ \begin{align} 
\text{minimize}& & f(\mathbf{x}) &= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2 \\
\text{subject to}& & x_{j+1} - x_j &\geq \varepsilon, j = 1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \\
& & min(x) &\geq 0 \\
& & max(x) & \leq 1 \\
\end{align}$$

---

**Expected Output 1**

$y = [0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$

$x = [0,\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon,\frac{3}{4}]$

**Expected Output 2**

$y = [0,0,0]$

$x = [0,\epsilon,2\cdot \epsilon]$

Of course, there are cases where no solution exist. Typically, in the second example if $2\cdot \epsilon > 1$, then there are no solution. In such case, the program should throw an error.

**Can you give me advice on how to go about solving this problem?**

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. "Strictly increasing" seems an important technical term; however, it only appears in the title.

Comment: 1. Are the y's strictly increasing?  Are the x's required to be strictly increasing?  As it stands it is not clear what the task is, so the question does not seem answerable in its current form.  Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking.  2. What approaches have you considered?  What have you tried?  Have you tried taking partial derivatives?  Have you tried dynamic programming?

Comment: Sorry about that. I rephrased the question while writing and forgot about the title. After sorting, "x"  is strictly increasing. It is a logical consequence of the third criteria. I removed this term from the title as it only bring confusion. Is the question easier to understand nwo?

Comment: @D.W. Please see the post again and especially the short version of the problem. I think it should make sense. I removed the term strictly increasing from the title as it was just an extra term that could bring confusion.

Comment: What have I tried? For the moment I have an algorithm that sorts the array and then start from the last element and goes down the array by increasing the spacing between any two elements if necessary (through subtraction) and then if the first element is below zero, I go back up to increase space between each element if necessary (through addition). If then the last element overpass zero, I try to jitter the data and see if it satisfies the condition and repeat it plenty of times. If it still does not work, I throw an error. It is definitely not a good algorithm but works most of the time.

Comment: That looks like how a mathematician would write down a non-linear optimization problem. I'd pick up a textbook on that topic.

Comment: x being strictly increasing isn't actually a logical consequence of the third condition.  I don't understand what the "when sorted" part of the short form is saying -- do you mean when the x's are sorted, the y's are sorted, or both are sorted?

Comment: @D.W. If `y` is sorted, then `x` will necessarily be sorted for the minimization condition to be fulfilled. Since `x`'s values cannot be identical, then it must be strictly increasing.

Comment: @Kittsil, that's all fine, but the question doesn't state/promise that the y values are sorted.

Comment: I used the expression "when sorted" so that I could say $x_1 \ge 0$ and $X_n \le 1$ instead of $max(x) \le 1$ and $min(x) \ge 0$. Sorry if that was confusing. I edited the post. (Note for question of performance that in the particular case, I want to apply the algorithm to, the input $x$ is already sorted).